# Error CS0103 when a variable is actually in the right scope

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this control (db is the Entity Framework context):

```
if (db.Sites.Any(s => s.Name.Equals(name))) throw new NameAlreadyInUseException(name);
```

When I run my tests and debug it fails giving me the error:

```
Error CS0103: the name 's' does not exist in the current context.
```

I honestly can't get my head around it and Google hasn't really been helping... any help is appreciated, thanks in advance. Isn't s used correctly here? (I'm still learning, so maybe I missed something but my code here looks ok to me)

Edit:
the debugger triggers the error on this line and I am not using s in any other place other than inside that if statement. (I edited the line to show what happens with the if)

Edit2: complete code of the function

```
public void CreateSiteOnDb(string connectionString, string name, int timezone, int sessionExpirationTimeInSeconds,
            double minimumBidIncrement)
        {
            CheckInput_CreateSiteOnDb(connectionString, name, timezone, sessionExpirationTimeInSeconds, minimumBidIncrement);

            try
            {
                using (var db = new AuctionSiteContext(connectionString))
                {
                    if (db.Sites.Any(s => s.Name.Equals(name))) throw new NameAlreadyInUseException(name);

                    var site = new Entities.Site
                    {
                        Name = name,
                        Timezone = timezone,
                        MinimumIncrement = minimumBidIncrement,
                        SessionExpirationInSeconds = sessionExpirationTimeInSeconds
                    };

                    db.Sites.Add(site);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch(NameAlreadyInUseException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                throw new UnavailableDbException();
            }
        }
```

Edit3: Error as shown during debugging

[image: screenshot from visual studio showing error during debugging]

Comment: Are you certain the error is on this line? Or are you trying to reference `s` somewhere else?

Comment: Agree with @DStanley are you trying to access 's' within the if statement scope somewhere?

Comment: Indeed - it would be easier to help if you could provide a [mcve]. Note that you could almost certainly use a `List<Site>` instead when coming up with an example, to avoid the EF aspect.

Comment: @DStanley  Yep, I'm sure the problem it's on this line since the debugger triggers here, and no, I don't use s anywhere else. I'm using it to throw an exception, the complete line is: 
`if (db.Sites.Any(s => s.Name.Equals(name))) throw new NameAlreadyInUseException(name);`

Comment: Can you add the full method code? Is this in a compiled library or in a template of some kind (e.g. MVC Razor page)?

Comment: "the debugger triggers the error on this line" - I'd expect this to be a *compiler* error, not something that is related to the debugger at all.

Comment: It may sound weird but have you added `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: @DStanley I've added the complete code. It's not in a compiled library, I'm writing the implementation of said function. (professor gave us the interface in a dll and the tests, we have to write the implementation so that the tests pass)

Comment: @JonSkeet honestly I thought the same, but it compiles without a problem, but during the execution fails and the debugger gives me this error on that line

Comment: @ilkerkaran yes, it wouldn't even compile otherwise :)

Comment: But that's a _compiler_ error. That error wouldn't come up in debugging unless the content is dynamically compiled somehow.  What's your development environment? (e.g. Visual Studio version or other toolset)

Comment: @DStanley I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I tried reproducing your code a little simplified dotnetfiddle, but I couldn't reproduce any error. You can take a look at the fiddle here, it compiles and runs without errors: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vpTJ3t

Comment: How *exactly* is the error shown? Is this an exception? If so, what's the exception type? What does the stack trace look like? How are you running this code? There's a lot we don't know here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've uploaded a screenshot of how the error appears in Visual Studio during debugging. The code is run through the tests

Comment: @bassfader this is also another problem I'm having. Sometimes I have the error, others I don't. It depends mainly on the test but that's the error I have (I just uploaded an image showing how it appears on VS)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in an extension or visualizer. The one that renders the pinned `dbcontext` and `s` variables. You can safely ignore it as a bug in that visualizer and isn't anything wrong with your code. It looks like the Resharper Inline Debugging Adornments. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/20173/inline_debugging.png

Comment: @jessehouwing which would be ok if the execution didn't fail, which it does since it throws the UnavailableDbException

Comment: That's a very different error than anything in the code so far. I suspect they're unrelated. What's the exact nameof the exception? This one doesn't google anything.

Comment: @jessehouwing  it's one of the exceptions defined by our professor, nothing standardised, but that's the one that catches the error in the try-catch

Comment: Try making this: `catch(Exception) { throw new UnavailableDbException(); }` into `catch(Exception e) { throw new UnavailableDbException(e); }` and set the breakpoint there, that should give you more details on what's going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206141/discussion-between-jessehouwing-and-trysme).

Comment: After two days I realized the problem was actually a bug in the visualizer as someone said and that the debugger continued the execution.
The problem that caused the failure was somewhere else.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help, I'm sorry if I made you loose time on this

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the right scope.

In the screenshot you are in the scope of `CreateSiteOnDb -> try -> using`, but `s` does not belong to that context.

In very basic terms `s => ....` is converted to function of a class, and it is called from inside `Any`. so let's assume that our expression is function named `Steve`. `Steve` would look like this:

```cs
bool Steve(ISite s)
{
  return s.Name.Equals(name);
}
```

this means `s` is the parameter of `Steve`, and is only valid inside `Steve`, which becomes `CreateSiteOnDb -> try -> using -> Any -> Steve`

So to see `s` you need to be in two more levels. Please, put your cursor inside the expression and then put a breakpoint.